# Updating Page Content Without Refreshing Page

Tags: real-time, updating

I want to update recent notifications on the user's dashboard without refreshing it whenever there is a change in database notification table...as in Facebook where posts and comments are updated in real time...doesn't require page refresh. How can I do it. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been using Node.js for a while now with its Socket.io API. It works just fine to use websockets to update content without refreshing it by generating signals from the server end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for a company called Realtime (http://www.realtime.co) and we developed a very cool framework to work with real-time data.

It works on the cloud, we offer a lot of different APIs, you don't need to install anything and you can get a free account (with 1.000.000 free messages and 30.000 users per month). It allows you to push data to browsers, meaning you won't be hammering your server with AJAX requests.

On browsers, it uses websockets, if available. For older, non-websocket browsers, we will transparently fallback to whatever is that your browser can use.

Check out http://www.realtime.co and http://www.xrtml.org for downloads and documentation. Please let me know if you need any help as I am the Developer Evangelist for Realtime :)

Answer (score 1):

It is something called `asynchronous`. Which you refresh the contents of a webpage or a DIV or anything else without reloading the page.

Actually you should use `AJAX` to load another page into a already present DIV in your page so it will be refreshed on  a time basis.

[AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/)

The documentation is really simple on w3 schools you can see there.

But the thing is you should use another page called a Handler or something to load and process the contents and then make them ready to be presented in your page and so you can load it time by time using javascript timers or etc.